# How to get notified when NSPersistentCloudKitContainer finish sync?

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

How to get notified when NSPersistentCloudKitContainer finish sync?

I am interested in **uploading** Core Data changes completion, because can be notified by Core Data easily if changes was downloaded from server.

Comment: Use the completion block.

Comment: Completion block from where?

Comment: @ElTomato Can you answer please, where can I found completion block when NSPersistentCloudKitContainer finish sync?